# EDIFACT Numbers

Tags: figure, edi, edifact

[EDIFACT-Numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIVCu.png)

Please, can someone help me with the figures / numbers yellow marked?

What are they for and how are they as well as with which priciple are set?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the element and segment numbers in EDIFACT message definitions are mainly there to be able to reference them clearly in documentation. When two sides are negotiating a message contract, it can help to be able to just reference composite `C040` or element `3127`. The numbers don't have any meaning other than being unique within the given EDIFACT standard (e.g. D96A).

Comment: Thanks a lot Dirk! I've now got half of the question replied. Where can I find the definitions and how are they originally ordered? It seems not all are put after the rule C010, C020, C030.... I'm curious since I found no detailed information about them, neither in EDIFACT, nor in X12, nor VDA etc.

Comment: EDIFACT is a UNECE project, you can find (a lot of) details here: https://www.unece.org/cefact/edifact/welcome.html. The main reason the segments aren't numbered in the order they appear in a message definition is because whenever a new version of the EDIFACT standard is released, the old segment numbers are carried over and new segments and elements are numbered after that. EDIFACT is a pretty old standard and has seen a lot of releases and updates over the decades, therefore the segment and element names aren't in the order they appear in a message but in the order they were designed.

Comment: Many thanks Dirk! You do help me a lot with the riddle on this issue. Wish you a nice weekend!